# How to read efficiently n folders from hdfs and write back in hbase using Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have to read 'n' folders which are present in hdfs file system using Apache Spark. Each folder contains 1 definition file and 1 .tsv file, and the definition file can vary in each folder, so i cannot club them all.
Now, once am done reading these 'n' folders I need to write it back to hbase tables.
Wanted to understand what is the optimised way of approaching this problem?

1 Solution what I have in mind is: In an iterative way read all 'n' folders 1 by 1 and once read is done write it again 1 by1 each 'n' folder.
The only drawback here is I have to make 'n' I/O calls which I feel is not efficient.